# Are there any services/apps/websites similar to Google Trips?

Tags: online-resources, mobile-apps, travel-tools

On May 1 2023 Google discontinued the [Google Trip Summaries](https://support.google.com/travel/?hl=en&visit_id=638192001495974449-1168211606&rd=2&topic=6228583#topic=7687752). For those unaware, Google Trip Summaries would automatically grab your flight/train ticket information and hotel information from your Gmail and create an itinerary/summary of your planned trip. It was a very useful and convenient tool to check your travel plans and create an itinerary of what you want to do.

Now that its shutdown, are there any other similar apps or services we can use. Even if they don't have any automations, atleast grabbing your plans from calendar and creating a trip summary would be useuful

Comment: I use tripit.com. (no advertisement or endorsement intended). It's not particularly good at managing changes to an itinerary, but otherwise it works fine for my needs

Comment: Sabre and Amadeus (the main GDS operators) also offer their services (the flight part of the app will only work if your ticket has been issued by an airline using their services of course)

Comment: wanderlog.com imports flight and hotel reservations into your plan from your email